# key in java - priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to learn java and I am stumped by this example- I can't find what the key is

```
public class OrderedArrayMaxPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {
    private Key[] pq;          // elements
```

This is the example of the priority queue .. i got it from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/OrderedArrayMaxPQ.java.html
I thought a priority queue should have a data + a priority value. I am not sure how these guys are doing it.

```
public class OrderedArrayMaxPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {
    private Key[] pq;          // elements
    private int N;             // number of elements

    // set inititial size of heap to hold size elements
    public OrderedArrayMaxPQ(int capacity) {
        pq = (Key[]) (new Comparable[capacity]);
        N = 0;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() { return N == 0;  }
    public int size()        { return N;       } 
    public Key delMax()      { return pq[--N]; }

    public void insert(Key key) {
        int i = N-1;
        while (i >= 0 && less(key, pq[i])) {
            pq[i+1] = pq[i];
            i--;
        }
        pq[i+1] = key;
        N++;
    }
```

Comment: Just to note, if you intend on using this code in a production environment, you should be aware that there will be an Unchecked Conversion warning on the array construction line which is unfortunately unavoidable, but I would recommend using a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation for.  Also (and probably more importantly), the `delMax()` method fails to null out the no-longer-used reference, which may prevent keys that have been removed from the queue from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

The priority is implemented within the `Key` implementation via its `Comparable` interface.

In the example you link to, they use `String` elements, so the priority is `String`'s implementation of `Comparable`.

If you wanted to implement, say, a numeric priority, you'd create a priority queue with your class, which would implement `Comparable`, comparing the numeric value of the priority field.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Key[]`, just `Comparable[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others say, focus on the comparable interface.  A good way to get a feel for how java implements priority queues is to note the fact that String, Integer, Float, and other classes implement the Comparator interface.

This means that , by the objects definition, it is comparable (<,>, or =) to other objects of the same type.

I would suggest , rather than learning about priority queues, you

1) play with the sorting of simpler java data structures like Vectors and TreeMaps.
2) Look through the Collections API.  Write a program which, for example, uses Collections.sort to sort some different lists.
3) Try to write an object which implements the Comparator interface, and sort a collection of these objects.